# Heroku - nil:NilClass Error in Altering Variable in Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, heroku

I recently implemented a views counter for certain pages on my test app on heroku.

It's a simple counter that just adds one view each time the user show action is accessed. It works as such:

```
 class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
      @product.views += 1
      @product.save
  end 

  ....
 end
```

This counter works fine on my local host, but on Heroku, there is an error:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
```

Now I have done some trouble shooting - the @product variable is definitely not nil. I have, for example, replaced the views/save lines with

```
 redirect_to root_path if @product.nil?
```

which didn't redirect to root_path - showing that the variable isn't really nil. Why is heroku doing this? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First round.

I'm sure you forgot to run your migrations so `.views` does not exist.

```
 rake db:migrate
```

Comment: basically.. the migration wasn't working on heroku (but it ran later when a rolled back and re-migrated). Thanks.